# pdfjs got a weird Syntax Error -- "?." which is not working on Edge, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, polyfills, pdf.js

I'am using the latest version of pdfjs to render my documents, but got a syntax error on Edge:

[image]

On pdf.js line 2366, found a weird syntax -- "?.", I have never seen that before.

[image]

The source code is in the file [api.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/d3f7959689b9ccd9b292ccebf73377370c64268a/src/display/api.js) line 1196.

[image]

So, here's my questions:

1. What is "?."
2. If it's not a bug, how can I make it work on my Edge?

My Edge version: Microsoft Edge 44.19041.1.0

BTW, pdfjs works fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?.` operator is called optional chaining. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

According to MDN, it is supported in "Edge 80". To support old browsers you can search to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill#:%7E:text=A%20polyfill%20is%20a%20piece,do%20not%20natively%20support%20it.).

It seems like you cannot really use a polyfill because it is an operator. [They say you need to transpile](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/frbct5/js_optional_chaining_polyfill/) your script. Transpiling simply takes your code (which does not support old browsers), then generates a code that supports old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to an "es5" distribution of pdfjs removed this error for me (on Edge 44.18362.449.0).

Comment: Yes, I was trying to switch an old version pdfjs to a new version, and using the old 'generic' comand. I fixed this problem using 'generic-es5' instead